# TOR 6 Not Working on Windows 10 32 Bit

Tags: windows

After automatically updating to TOR 6 on Windows 10, I cannot now run it.  The TOR browser process starts then dies with no error reports.  I have tried new installs but all do the same thing.  I have tried running without Firewall and Virus Scanner but the result is the same.  Given that I have not changed anything on my PC, I can only suspect that the latest version has a compatibility issue.  Is there any way I can revert to an earlier version?  Getting desperate now as I have tried everything I could find to sort this.

Comment: Same here for windows 10 64 bit, also tried the beta version and that does the same.

Comment: UPDATE:  To prove that it is TOR 6.0 that is the problem, I have reverted to 5.5.5 which runs correctly.  Someone with more knowledge than me needs to look at why TOR 6.0 won't run on Windows 10

Comment: I am having the same identical problem. I would like to revert back to version 5.5.5 (while this compability issues with 6 are fixed). Where can I find version 5.5.5? I haven't been able to download it from anywhere. Thank you

Comment: Same for xp sp3. Much experiment got nowhere. Lucky found backup of earlier version works fine.